# Azure Frontdoor or traffic manager

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager, azure-front-door, azure-regions

Just wanted the recommendations in using azure frontdoor or azure traffic manager for my 2 different web apps hosted on different regions? Can we use both together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you should use the one that makes more sense. Traffic Manager you can work with different algorithms when routing to the right region, while Front Door you don't have this flexibility.

On the other hand, Front Door offers some features like Web Application Firewall (WAF) and SSL Offloading that may be interesting in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, Thiago for your reply. I just wanted to see if we have Traffic manager for routing to right regions and can at each region can we have frontdoor?

Comment: you'll have an additional hop. In my opinion, Front Door should be the entry point.

Comment: Ok, So you mean that Front Door should be entry point then Traffic manager at each region? or only frontdoor and no need of adding traffic manager?

Answer (score 2):

Both Azure front door and traffic manager are deployed in a region agnostic way by azure to help load balance instances between region pairs. If you are hosting web applications using azure app service, the recommend solution for load balancing between regions is Front Door since your traffic is Http(s). (whereas a traffic manager would work nice if you are running virtual machines in different regions and want to load balance between them)

And if you want to further load balance traffic between different web apps in the same region, use an  azure application gateway. (your front door directs user traffic to a region, and within that region, the application gateway directs traffic to a healthy web app.)

You can read this for a decision tree of the load balancing options provided by microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview#decision-tree-for-load-balancing-in-azure

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rimaz and Jeremy. My web app will be interacting to APIM for APIs that are hosted on-premise. So in this case we can go with frontdoor only. Can we use frontdoor to redirect the user to healthy web app? or we should have application gateway also?

Comment: Hi Rajesh. Yes you can use just azure front door only to redirect users to a healthy web app since you are hosting your API web app in two regions and need to load balance between 2 or more azure regions. You do NOT need an application gateway for your scenario. See here how to configure front door for your apps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/quickstart-create-front-door